# How do droid names work?

Tags: star-wars

Droids are machines, with model years and presumably updates, e.g., R5-M4 being more advanced than R2-D2. However, they all seem to have fairly unique personalities, and aside from battle droids and labor droids, you almost never see two droids that look the same. Are there a bunch of R2-D2s rolling around off-screen, or do they somehow have unique designations? Like R2-D2 was followed on the production line by R2-D3, R2-D4, etc.

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate, he was asking if all droids have 4 digit names, and I'm asking if all droids have unique names

Comment: @phantom42 - Ah! That's the one that I was thinking of.